# Unable to get value of the property 'checked': object is null or undefined Error

Tags: javascript, asp.net

We have an application with the below java script code which is giving the error,

> unable to get the value of the property check box

, we need to change the below code in the format `<%=Checkbox1.ClientID%>`. Please help to change the below code in that format,

I have multiple lines of code like below, because of that I need to use predefined variable "crtlName"

```
var ctrlName="CheckBox"

if(document.getElementById(ctrlName + "1").checked)
{
  document.getElementById(ctrlName + "Table1").style.display ='inline';
}
```

Comment: Inspect the actual element not the asp defined value. Are you certain that the id of the field is Checkbox? Generally if obj is null or undefined on a getElementById it's because it couldn't find the element you are referencing.

Comment: Why this? `document.getElementById(document.getElementById`

Comment: Actually we are building the controls dynamically, so for example I kept the name as Checkbox, this code is working from past 7years, may be because of latest patches in the browsers it is not working now. When I checked in the internet, most of the people suggested to change the old code to <%=Checkbox1.ClientID%> method, as I am building the controls dynamically, I need to use the user defined variable in these fields and I am getting error when I used that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to modify your code for you, instead here are some samples may help you solve your question.

If I didn't get it wrong. Your major question is how to use inline expression like `<%=Checkbox1.ClientID%>` in javascript. you can do something as following

```
var checkBox1 = document.getElementById('<%= CheckBox1.ClientID %>');
```

Secondly, you mentioned your controls are generated dynamically which means you may need to achieve something like `variable.ClientID` in javascript area.

```
var checkBox2 = document.getElementById(
    '<%= ((CheckBox)this.Page.FindControl(_checkBoxId)).ClientID %>');
```

then set `_checkBoxId` in the code-behind

```
public string _checkBoxId;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _checkBoxId = "CheckBox2";
}
```

Finally, compare to the solution above I prefer using attribute selector

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[id*=CheckBox]:checked");
```